# How to run wine in docker with ubuntu:20.04 base (works with ubuntu:18.04 base)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, wine

The following works when built from ubunut:18.04. But when I change it to build from ubuntu:20.04, it fails.

On the first run, it works, but gives these errors:

```
wine@wine:~$ wine regedit
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/wine/.wine'
X Error of failed request:  BadRROutput (invalid Output parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  9 (RRGetOutputInfo)
  Serial number of failed request:  187
  Current serial number in output stream:  187
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
0012:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0012:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
0012:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 183
0012:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 14007
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x800736b7
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 800736b7
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 800736b7
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/home/wine/.wine" has been updated.
002f:err:clipboard:convert_selection Timed out waiting for SelectionNotify event
002f:err:clipboard:convert_selection Timed out waiting for SelectionNotify event
```

All subsequent runs do not work, and give these errors:

```
wine@wine:~$ wine regedit
0014:err:module:DelayLoadFailureHook failed to delay load setupapi.dll.SetupDiGetClassDevsW
wine: Call from 0x7b032f82 to unimplemented function setupapi.dll.SetupDiGetClassDevsW, aborting
wine: Unimplemented function setupapi.dll.SetupDiGetClassDevsW called at address 7B032F82 (thread 0014), starting debugger...
^C000d:err:user:load_desktop_driver failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winex11.drv"
0020:err:user:load_desktop_driver failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winex11.drv"
^C0020:err:module:DelayLoadFailureHook failed to delay load comctl32.dll.InitCommonControlsEx
wine: Call from 0x7b032f82 to unimplemented function comctl32.dll.InitCommonControlsEx, aborting
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
        && apt update \
        && apt install -y --install-recommends apt-utils \
        && apt install -y --install-recommends wine-stable wine32 \
        && useradd -m wine
ENV HOME="/home/wine"
WORKDIR $HOME
USER wine
CMD /bin/bash
```

Build:

```
docker build -t wine .
```

Create the container:

```
docker create -it \
    --user="wine" \
    --hostname="wine" \
    --name="wine" \
    --env="DISPLAY" \
    --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix" \
    --network="host" \
    wine
```

Run it:

```
docker start wine
```

Open a shell into the running docker container:

```
docker exec -it wine /bin/bash
```

Run regedit inside the container as a test:

```
wine regedit
```

When the container is built from ubuntu:18.04, it works.

When the container is built from ubuntu:20.04, it brings up the regedit window once, but throws errors. Subsequent calls to "wine regedit" do not work, and errors are still thrown.

The errors suggest an issue opening X windows, but it's able to open regedit once, which is strange because it has to be accessing X successfully for it to be able to do that.

Comment: share the error you are getting

Comment: When I created this post, I provided what I thought to be the most relevant errors in an effort to be succinct. But since I'm not sure what's causing the problem, I realize I should have provided the messages in their entirety. I have now edited the question to provide them. I also added the docker create command, which I originally forgot to include.